# weld surface to the other, without seams appearing?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

how are you guys

finishing the video tutorial below:
How can I weld one surface to the other, without seams appearing, after aligning them?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s

thanks

Comment: is it not explained in the video? Snaping with Shrinkwrap assigned to a vertex group?

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: maybe tell if you failed and why, I've tested the same method and I'm not sure it always works